# Where can I visit former Nazi camps and prisons in Europe?

Tags: europe, museums, world-war-ii

Some months ago I visited the [NS Documentation Center of the City of Cologne](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NS_Documentation_Centre_of_the_City_of_Cologne). The museum was very interesting for me because the building wasn't destroyed during World War II and I could see the former Gestapo prison with inscriptions and drawings done by prisoners on the walls.

Now I am looking for other museums in Europe dedicated to memorializing the victims of the Nazi regime like prisons and concentration camps where I can see more than just photos and videos, or some memorials built after the war. I want to see the death camps from inside, prison cells or gas chambers.

Comment: Too short for an answer, I think, but this certainly is said to be an impressive one: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auschwitz_concentration_camp

Comment: the list of concentration camps has almost no end. I "liked" Buchenwald, near Weimar. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buchenwald_concentration_camp

Comment: http://www.destination-munich.com/odeonsplatz.html, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treblinka_extermination_camp, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khatyn_massacre.  You should narrow down the geographical area.

Comment: @Karlson I'm looking for buildings that have survived during the WW2 and not only some monuments that are build later

Comment: @Dirty-flow Treblinka, Buchenwald, Auschwiz all survived WWII.  If you're looking for something more in context of NS and specific.  http://needleberlin.com/2010/03/27/nazi-ruins-albert-speers-only-surviving-works-in-berlin/, http://sitemaker.umich.edu/artunderfascism/architecture

Comment: @Dirty-flow http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolf's_Lair

Comment: @Karlson Treblinka is a memorial nowadays. The camp has  been dismantled in 1943.

Comment: @MarcelC. I know.  Comment was left before the edit.

Comment: @Karlson - OK. But anyway, the place has still quite a particular athmosphere today with all this memorial stones in the middle of a wood ...

Comment: @Dirty-flow - I would consider to change the title. It's not really 3rd Reich museums that you are looking for but rather Nazi prisons and camps. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @MarcelC. you're right, so I changed the title

Comment: Did anyone go "WTF?" when reading the new title?

Comment: If you're interested in other remaining Nazi buildings besides prison camps, the places that gave me the chills were in Nuremberg: Zeppelin Field, which was the Nazi party rally grounds you will recognize from old films. Only the Nazi symbols were destroyed - the rest was simply abanodoned and is very recognizable and very large. Right next to it is the only building Speer built for Hitler's "Germania", which now is "pierced" by a memorial/museum. Wikipedia [Documentation Center Nazi Party Rally Grounds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Documentation_Center_Nazi_Party_Rally_Grounds)

Comment: @andrewgrimm Why?

Comment: @Karlson At the time I wrote that comment, it said "Nazi camps and prisons in Europe", rather than "Former Nazi camps and prisons in Europe". As if they were still operating!

Comment: What do you wish to see? What do you expect from seeing gas chambers? Buchenwald has mixed reputation because you enter the facility through the gate "Jedem das seine" and only see the huge square. There were barracks there but the are gone for decades.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- In Krakow, PL, you can visit the Schindler's Factory, about what Schindler did to save jews giving them jobs. A really good museum.
- In Oświęcim, PL, you can visit [Auschwitz concentration camp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auschwitz_concentration_camp) (Auschwitz is the german writing of the town's name), you can go there from Krakow or Katowice by bus or train. You will see the horror factory-sized.
- In Budapest, HU, you can visit the House of Terror, which is about [Arrow Cross Party](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_Cross_Party), the hungarian national socialist party.

Comment: The House of Terror is mostly about the victims of the communists.

Comment: In Poland there is also [Stutthof concentration camp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stutthof_concentration_camp) that is 34 km east of Gdańsk.

Answer (score 5):

The locations are very well known.  Just as a starting point you can take a look at the [Map as of 1942](http://www.facinghistory.org/sites/facinghistory.org/files/European-concentration-camp-map.pdf), so using the map and in addition to @travelot answer:

- [Majdanek concentration camp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majdanek_concentration_camp)
- [Dachau](http://www.kz-gedenkstaette-dachau.de/index-e.html)
- [Babiy Yar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babi_Yar)
- [Khatyn'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khatyn_massacre)
- [Mauthausen](http://en.mauthausen-memorial.at/)

Answer (score 5):

[Fort Breendonk](http://www.breendonk.be/index.html) is probably not the most famous Nazi camp out there, but it is well preserved and far from being the least interesting to visit.

The [Hadamar Euthanasia Centre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamar_Euthanasia_Centre) can be visited too. It is a psychiatric hospital today [but has a memorial](http://www.gedenkstaette-hadamar.de/). And it is not too far from Mainz. Can be done on a day trip.

Answer (score 5):

Terezin (Czech Republic), former Jewish Concentration camp and a prison. Terezin is a fortress town from 18th century. Features:

- Guided tours in the prison (in former military area).
- Large Jewish cemetery.
- Several buildings in the town are devoted to the Museum of Holocaust.

More info: [Theresienstadt concentration camp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theresienstadt_concentration_camp), [Terezin Memorial](http://www.pamatnik-terezin.cz/en?lang=en)

Answer (score 2):

In the Netherlands the former camp Westerbork is now a memorial/museum. There are other memorials at the former camp Amersfoort, I think at Vught, and at several relevant places (like the execution grounds at Waalsdorper plain near the Hague where hundreds were brought from prisons to be shot).