# Former Gulag camps in Russia

Tags: russia, museums

I have already asked a simular question about [Former Nazi camps and prisons in Europe](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14165/former-nazi-camps-and-prisons-in-europe), now I would like to know if there are any Gulag camps that I can see from the inside?

Comment: seeing as many of the camps are still in operation, many others are in oblasts still closed to foreigners, and of course many of them are in extremely remote areas, unlikely. Countries generally don't like you looking closely at how they mistreat their "unwanted". Germany is an exception in that they didn't get much of a choice in the matter.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Given how many [camps there were](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%93%D0%A3%D0%9B%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0) you could be sure to find a few:

- [Соло-Тур](http://northural.ru/tours/tury_po_mestam_gulaga/) offers tour in the North Urals (info in Russian)
- [Blog on Tour of "Dneprovskiy" near Magadan](http://alkrylov.livejournal.com/260448.html) with contact information on how to get one set up. (Russian)
- [DVS Tour](http://www.dvs-tour.ru/index.php?newsid=193) - Information about the tour is in Russian but the company provide information in English as well though not about the tour.
- [Tour of Camp "Perm-36"](http://adrutours.com/neobichnoe/44-neobichniepriklucheniya/169-turyi-pamyati-po-mestam-gulaga) (Russian) [Same Tour in English](http://www.uraltourism.com/perm36.php)

I am sure there are a few more that I haven't found.

**Additional Info**

You can also visit one of the first and the largest labor camp open in the 1920s which is now again a Monastery.  [Соловецкий Лагерь Особенного Назначения (СЛОН)](http://solovki-monastyr.ru/abbey/soviet-period/slon/) was closed in 1933.

Answer (score 11):

in my opinion, the fullest information and addresses of museums, you can find here:

- [GULag Museum](http://www.gmig.ru/info-english/)
- [Virtual Gulag Museum](http://www.gulagmuseum.org/showObject.do?object=33736&language=1)

Answer (score 7):

Not exactly in Russia (but still closer to Moscow than Magadan), I visited ALZHIR gulag near Astana in Kazakhstan a few years ago. It is more a memorial than a real "camp" as you might imagine it. I had a picture of one of these labor camps in my mind, it doesn't look like this. If you drive around you can still see some old Kolkhozs where people are still living, and they still have these soviet signs. Basically it is a vast area where the people (mainly women and children) were held in huts and worked in the fields.

[ALZHIR camp near Astana](http://alzhir-eng.ucoz.ru/)

Answer (score 3):

Perm-36 near Perm West of the ural mountains claim to be the only open to the public GULAG (Museum). There are different reoprts on the internet that it has been shut down but I have [visited there in Summer 2016](https://blog.foxel.org/2016/08/01/perm-36-das-gulag-museum/). It was worth the visit.

When traveling the Area you can find many aktive Prison camps. For example see [here](https://blog.foxel.org/2016/08/05/bruecken-bauen-nach-kulimsunt/), last photo.