# What are the recommended concentration camp tours near Berlin?

Tags: germany, tours, museums, berlin

My partner and I are planning a trip to Berlin.  Among other things, we would like to visit a concentration camp, preferably do a tour.  Are there any nearby for a day /half-day trip?  What are some recommended tours?

Comment: related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14165/former-nazi-camps-and-prisons-in-europe

Comment: I think the questions should be merged

Comment: @Karlson, that question is more broad in terms of location.  I think this question (and answer) would be more useful for users doing a search for "berlin + concentration camps"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend you [Sachsenhausen concentration camp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sachsenhausen_concentration_camp). It's only 35km from Berlin. Here is a [list of guided tours](http://www.stiftung-bg.de/gums/en/index.htm) that they offer.

Here are some more tours: [Insider Tour](http://www.insidertour.com/tours.php/cat/27/id/43/title/Sachsenhausen_Concentration_Camp), [Berlin Walks](http://www.berlinwalks.com/tours_sachsenhausen.html), which also do other tours in Berlin. They are walking tours where you meet at a particular time and take the train to the destination.